# Connect to SSH Tunnel in Mac App SDK

Tags: macos, sdk, ssh, reachability, tunnel

I'm working on a Mac App that processes some data from online.
One of the options is that it supports SSH tunnel's for getting data.  Ideally, the app would connect to an SSH tunnel using some user settings and then work (i.e. all network connections used in the app go through this tunnel, which should be forwarding port 80 to a remote server [so, if I were to implement a WebView or other component, they would work through the SSH tunnel automatically]) automatically, all remote services being routed through the tunnel.

This is a new area of code to me.  I've read from somebody for something similar that I could use Reachability, which sounds interesting, but I really don't know.  Can somebody point me in the direction of a tutorial on this kind of code?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a chance to speak to an Apple Engineer about this and it is not possible.